# Alternatives to GitHub Pages?

Tags: git, web, web-hosting, github-pages

So I'm doing research for a project and I am wondering if there exists any web applications that offer similar services to GitHub Pages.

As in, a free (or cheap) web host where the collaborators push to a central git repository to make the changes and those changes get deployed live.

Comment: free and probably the best alternative https://www.netlify.com/github-pages-vs-netlify/

Answer (score 7):

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is another possible option:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

Or even better: http://www.lemiffe.com/how-to-deploy-a-static-page-to-heroku-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/). It has a free tier and allow you to [automatically publish your site from VCS](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/).

Answer (score 4):

[Aerobatic](http://www.aerobatic.com) is a static hosting service that's integrated directly with Bitbucket as an add-on. Features include CDN, wildcard SSL certs, HTTP basic auth, and more.

Comment: It's cool and pretty much what I searched for. However, when I launch my site on GitHub Pages it just works, whereas on Aerobatic, the Jquery and js part is not working... Did I make any mistake or is Js forbidden on Aerobatic?

Comment: Hi @frankenapps, I'm guessing this may have something to do with relative versus absolute URLs. Aerobatic certainly supports the hosting of JavaScript. Pls feel free to send a ticket to support@aerobatic.com with more details.

Comment: Aerobatic s transitioning from a Bitbucket add-on to a standalone CLI and web dashboard. However, **Custom domains and wildcard SSL certs are no longer part of our free tier** after 1st March 2017.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just host a static website, consider taking a look at [CloudCannon](http://cloudcannon.com/).
You can also use Amazon services like S3 and Cloud Front: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html